# Should protected fields in an Abstract super class be accessed using super or this in sub-classes?

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract-class

Suppose I have the following Abstract class.

```
public abstract class Account {
    protected String Id;
    protected double balance;

    public Account(String Id, double balance) {
        this.Id = Id;
        this.balance = balance;
    }
}
```

And the following subclass

```
public class CheckingAccount {

    public CheckingAccount(String Id, double balance) {
        super(Id, balance)
        if(super.balance > 10_000) this.balance += 200;
    }
}
```

Both 'this' and 'super' are allowed in the context of the subclass when accessing a protected member. Is it better to use one over the other? 'super' makes it explicit where that field comes from. I understand I can just use `balance` without specifying the implicit parameter but I was just curious in terms of how this is utilized in practice if one wanted to specify the implicit parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd argue you shouldn't use any `protected` fields, to enforce encapsulation. Provide a `protected void addToBalance(double value)` method would be the cleaner way.

> I was just curious in terms of how this is utilized in practice if one wanted to specify the implicit parameter

For somewhat academic reasons, here's where it makes a difference:

```
public abstract class Account {
    protected String Id;
    protected double balance;

    public Account(String Id, double balance) {
        this.Id = Id;
        this.balance = balance;
    }
}

public class CheckingAccount {
    // overwrite existing field
    protected double balance;

    public CheckingAccount(String Id, double balance) {
        super(Id, balance);
        this.balance = balance;
        if(super.balance > 10_000) this.balance += 200;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a note, you can't override a variable. What is happening here is hiding, `CheckingAccount` will actually have both variables

Comment: Is CheckingAccount  extending from Account? If no extending, WHY super(Id, balance) here? If Extending, why declaring balance in CheckingAccount class again?

Answer (score 2):

Since CheckingAccount inherits protected field **balance** from Account so it DOES NOT matter using **super** or **this** keyword to access the field balance in CheckingAccount class. However, I prefer 'this'.

If there is a protected method in Account class (base class) and there is a its overridden method in CheckingAccount class, you will have to carefully use **super** or **this** in this case because they are not the same body implementation!